# bootstrap 4 aligning div's in a row and by the top boundary

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to align and image and an div inline. I also want the top's of the image and div to be aligned aswell. This is what I have so far

```
<div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/333/nature/2" class="img-fluid d-inline-block">
<div class="comment d-inline-block">
    <div class="comment-header">
        <span>title</span>
    </div>
    <blockquote>comment</blockquote>
</div>
```

I tried the class d-inline-block and it gets close to what I'm looking for but i need the text to be at the top.

You can see here:http://www.bootply.com/zpj12TL4wI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 includes a utility class for that: `align-top`. **No extra CSS** is needed...

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/333/nature/2" class="img-fluid">
    <div class="comment d-inline-block align-top">
        <div class="comment-header">
            <span>title</span>
        </div>
        <blockquote>comment</blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/wtAOA1JPn1

Answer (score 1):

Just a vertical-align change is what ya need:

```
.comment {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```